# How to do mapping for two objects and array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapping

I have such a object and array which I received response from my server. I need to convert that to second format at below in order to print the value in the website. Is this something need to do object mapping? or parse JSON or please kindly help.

`{"header":["SEOUL","BUSAN","NAMPODONG"],"data":[[38,"CAPITAL","M31"]]}`,

Convert from Above to below

```
'{"SEOUL" : "38", "BUSAN" : "CAPITAL", "NAMPODONG" : "M31"}'

var finalObj = {};
response.header.forEach(function(item, index) {
finalObj[item] = response.data[0][index];
});
```

Above code is working fine as it create variable and loop for header and get its value and printed in html. the header and data are from the server so when I enter something let say "A" then it will look for SEOUL header then print 38 in html as tables are looks below.

key value : A

header : SEOUL BUSAN    NAMPODONG

data :    38    CAPITAL  M31

I do have a lot of data in the database, above is just an example. So let say I enter B then the B is not in database so I want to see the value "No found" in html but this code printing nothing so not sure whether it was proceed or not.

Comment: Is it an object or a JSON string?

Comment: So you want a filter mechanism. How does the filter work? Why is `A` selecting the first object?

Answer (score 3):

Create a variable & loop over the `object.header` to get each key and `object.data[0]` to get its value

```js
var myObj = {
  "header": ["SEOUL", "BUSAN", "NAMPODONG"],
  "data": [
    [38, "CAPITAL", "M31"]
  ]
}
var tempObj = {};
myObj.header.forEach(function(item, index) {
  tempObj[item] = myObj.data[0][index]


})
console.log(tempObj)
```

Comment: `data` is probably going to have more entries in it.

Comment: Thank you so much!! :-) @brk

Answer (score 2):

As you received it from server – I assume that it is JSON string.

Basically you have two arrays here that you want to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to an object.
So I would do it like this:

```js
const object = JSON.parse('{"header":["SEOUL","BUSAN","NAMPODONG"],"data":[[38,"CAPITAL","M31"]]}');

const result = object.header.reduce(function(accumulator, element, i){
  accumulator[element] = object.data[0][i] // You had nested array here so I have to get first element.
  return accumulator;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

I assumed that nested array for `data` attribute is some kind of formatting mistake. If it's not – you have to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) though it's elements first and only then reduce.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [zipObj](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipObj) from Ramda library.

The code would look like this:

```js
const res = {"header":["SEOUL","BUSAN","NAMPODONG"],"data":[[38,"CAPITAL","M31"]]}

const obj = R.zipObj(res.header, res.data[0])
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@latest/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the new objects with the wanted keys.

The result is an array with objects, because your data is a nested array with actually only one array. But it looks like taht data could contain more than one row.

```js
var data = { header: ["SEOUL", "BUSAN", "NAMPODONG"], data: [[38, "CAPITAL", "M31"]] },
    result = data.data.map(a => Object.assign(...data.header.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: a[i] }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the `data` array of arrays into another array of object using as keys the strings in `header` array:

```js
function transform(obj) {
  return obj.data.map(function(subArray) {             // for each subArray in the data array
    return subArray.reduce(function(o, val, i) {       // create a new object o which...
      o[ obj.header[i] ] = val;                        // has key-value pairs where value is the current element of subArray and key is its equivalent (item at the same index) from header array
      return o;
    }, {});
  });
}


var obj = {"header":["SEOUL","BUSAN","NAMPODONG"],"data":[[38,"CAPITAL","M31"], [10,"OTHER","M01"]]};
var result = transform(obj);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @HelloWorld I don't understand. Can you elaborate more on that. Probably in edit the question for clarity as comments won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the responses above are good as they are, but here is an alternative using reduce in case you didn't know about it

```js
var response = {
  "header": ["SEOUL", "BUSAN", "NAMPODONG"],
  "data": [
    [38, "CAPITAL", "M31"]
  ]
};

var result = response.header.reduce(function(accum, v, i) {
    accum[v] = response.data[0][i];
    return accum;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```